# AndroidManifest.xml errors

Tags: java, android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.android">
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
    <activity android:name=".hba1c" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

I'm trying to learn Java and need some help with AndroidManifest.xml

My little hello world project is working code-wise, but I'm confused with making changes to the manifest. Specifically, in the code above package name is "com.android"  and in data/app my app shows up as com.android-1.apk. When I try to change it to something like com.jocala or com.jocala.hba1c I get package R does not exist errors through my compile, which fails.

What changes do I need to make? Anything else here that is glaringly bad?

I am working using Ant, VI and the Linux console, no Eclipse.

Comment: i wouldn't use com.android for your own classes, com.android is a package that should already exist in your android library. That might be the source of your problem, whatever it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change the package of the java code, let it in accordance with the package which you defined in the manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest holds meta-data corresponding to your android application. Hence, if you needs changes in the package name, make the changes in the java files, change the package name there, there is no sense making a change here. The only changes that are majorly done in the manifest are `activity` related(for beginners). Have a read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).